# Why temp.data == temp.next.data gives an error?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am doing a question of **eliminating duplicates from LinkedList**.  have written this code in the if statement first I have written `if(curr.data == curr.next.data)` but it is showing wrong and in one test case it is showing runtime error. Isn't Both are same? What is the difference in using (curr.data.equals(curr.next.data))?

```
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
        //Your code goes here
        if (head == null)
            return null;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> curr = head;
        while(curr.next != null)
        {
            if(curr.data == curr.next.data)
            {
                curr.next = curr.next.next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Difference between `==` and `equals()` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java. And do you know what is input for that test case?

Comment: @LinuxGeek No, Testcases are locked

Comment: @anarchist912 that's Java

Comment: I think you should consider @LinuxGeek 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while(curr.next != null)
```

to

```
while(curr != null)
```

In you `if` block you are checking `curr.next = curr.next.next` but what if `curr.next.next` is itself `null`, if it is `null` then your condition in `while` will cause an error.

Comment: Will it cause an error if you set `curr.next` to `null`? I think it will just end the `while` loop as the condition is not met anymore. PS: It is `curr` not `cur`.

Comment: @anarchist912 When `curr` itself is null then how would you access `curr.next` (as he/she had done in `while`). Consider there are only 2 nodes in the linked list and both of which has value 10. Now try running the loop, `if` condition is true so `curr` will be set to `curr.next.next` (which is `null`) so when it reaches `while` again condition `curr.next != null` will cause error as `curr` is already `null`. And yeah thank you I changed `cur` with `curr` now